# Java 11 Convert List of Strings to Map<UUID,String>

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, java-11

I am trying to convert the list of strings to Map as below but am getting a compilation error `no instance(s) of type variable(s) K, T exist so that UUID conforms to Function<? super T, ? extends K>`, can someone please help me with it?

```
List.of("john","jack", "jill")
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(UUID.randomUUID(), name ->name));
```

Comment: What compilation error you are getting?

Comment: `no instance(s) of type variable(s) K, T exist so that UUID conforms to Function<? super T, ? extends K>`

Comment: `k -> UUID.randomUUID()`, not `UUID.randomUUID()`. You need a function, not a uuid, for the key generator argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Map<UUID, String> collect = 
        List.of("john", "jack", "jill")
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> UUID.randomUUID(), name -> name));
```

Comment: Hello! welcome to SO! Please add few lines of explanation of why the existing code does not work. What changes you have made and how does it fix the existing code. 
However small they are they will help the other people having the same problem.